# Calculating number of duplicated rows

Tags: sql-server

I am confused why those queries are returning different number of records, please note that XXX table contains only three columns A,B,C

Query 1)

```
SELECT SUM (Counts) FROM 
    (
        SELECT Count(*) Counts FROM dbo.XXX 
              GROUP BY A,B,C
              HAVING COUNT(*) = 1
    ) T
```

Query 2)

```
SELECT A, B, C
  FROM [dbo].XXX
  GROUP BY A,B,C
```

Comment: because they are different queries? 1. has a having clause to only return results where the `count = 1`, and 2. doesn't

Comment: 2nd query is simple select statement with group by and 1st query is summing up the counts n sub query..obviously it will give different result set

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perhaps because your first query is only summing groups that have a group by count exactly equal to 1. Your second query will return all counts, whether the group by count is one or more.

So, it's possible that the combination of A, B and C occurs more than once. And if this is the case, your counts won't be the same.

Comment: A,B,C is the whole table

Comment: @Costa - It doesn't matter if it's the whole table. I'm not even sure what you mean by that. What I'm saying is that you must have in your table cases where the values of A and B and C occur more than once. Because, if they didn't the two queries would return the same results.

Answer (score 0):

Query 1 is counting the number of records for which A, B & C are unique in the table.

Query 2 is giving you the unique combinations of A, B & C in the table.